# Bedeutung von »in der Leitung sein«

Tags: translation, idiom

Ich lese jetzt das Buch *Milch und Kohle* von Ralf Rothmann um mein Deutsch zu üben. Auf Seite 12 steht der Satz:

> Das Telefon klingelte, ein gedämpfter Ton unter der Brokathülle, und ich lief ins Wohnzimmer. Doch als ich abhob, war schon niemand mehr in der Leitung.

Kann jemand diesen Satz ins Englische übersetzen? Besonders interessiert mich: Bedeutet der Ausdruck *in der Leitung sein* eigentlich *to be on the line*?

Comment: Mh, das Schließen der Frage ich so n' bisschen grenzwertig, finde ich. I retract my close vote, since an attempt has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Du hast Recht. In historischen Zeiten (die Älteren werden sich noch erinnern) hatten alle Telefone ein Kabel, genannt *Leitung*. *In dieser Leitung* war der Gesprächspartner. Wenn also jemand *in der Leitung ist*, würde ich auf Englisch sagen *he's in the call*, *he's on the other side (of the phone)* oder ähnliches.

Ich bin mir bei der englischen Präposition nicht sicher; ich schwanke zwischen *to be **in** the line* und ***on*** the line. Jemand wird mich da sicherlich verbessern können.

Den letzten Satz würde ich folgendermaßen übersetzen:

> But when I picked it up, the call had already been left.

Comment: Der Großteil der Strecke zwischen zwei Telefonen wird auch heute noch mit Kabeln realisiert.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Joar, aber die sieht man nicht. Die verschwindet ja aus dem Funkmasten in den Untergrund, um erst beim nächsten Funkmasten wieder aufzutauchen ;)

Comment: @Jan: du meinst, man kann heutzutage gar nicht mehr AUF der Leitung stehen? :D

Comment: @Gerhard Oh du glaubst gar nicht, wie lang meine Leitung so manchmal ist! :D

Comment: Historisch? Erinnern? Ich brauche nur mein Telefon ansehen. OK, es ist ein Schnurlostelefon, insofern geht die Leitung auch nur bis zur Basisstation; andererseits, wenn das nicht zählen sollte, muss ich nur zur Arbeit gehen, da steht dann ein klassisches kabelgebundenes Telefon im Büro.